# Dummy columns if row contains string

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have a data set that could look like this:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
               col1=c("UX1", "UX3", "UX2"),
               col2=c("UX2", "UX1", "UX1"),
               col3=c("PROC1", "PROC2", "PROC3"),
               col4=c("PROC3", "PROC3", "PROC1")
               )
```

output:

```
  id col1 col2  col3  col4
1  1  UX1  UX2 PROC1 PROC3
2  2  UX3  UX1 PROC2 PROC3
3  3  UX2  UX1 PROC3 PROC1
```

and I would like the output to look like this:

```
x2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),  
           col1=c("UX1", "UX3", "UX2"),
           col2=c("UX2", "UX1", "UX1"),
           col3=c("PROC1", "PROC2", "PROC3"),
           col43=c("PROC3", "PROC3", "PROC1"),

           UX1=c(1,1,1),
           UX2=c(1,0,1),
           UX3=c(0,1, 0),
           PROC1 =c(1,0,1),
           PROC2=c(0,1,0),
           PROC3 = c(1,1,1))
```

Wanted output:

```
  id col1 col2  col3 col43 UX1 UX2 UX3 PROC1 PROC2 PROC3
1  1  UX1  UX2 PROC1 PROC3   1   1   0     1     0     1
2  2  UX3  UX1 PROC2 PROC3   1   0   1     0     1     1
3  3  UX2  UX1 PROC3 PROC1   1   1   0     1     0     1
```

So basicalle to create a dummy if a row contains a string. I can create `dummy.data.frame` using `library(dummies)` e.g.

`y <- dummy.data.frame(x)`

but this approch thinks that (for example) UX1 in column one is different than UX1 in column two. So dummy.data.frame does not work...

Comment: @Tino: This approch is basically the same as dummy.data.frame. Can you please look at the question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea via `tidyverse`. We first `gather` all except the `id` variable. We then `spread` to get the required structure and use a simply `replace` to 'dummify' our data, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>% 
 gather(var, val, -id) %>% 
 spread(val, var, fill = 0) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-id), funs(replace(., . != 0, 1)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   id PROC1 PROC2 PROC3 UX1 UX2 UX3
> 1  1     1     0     1   1   1   0
> 2  2     0     1     1   1   0   1
> 3  3     1     0     1   1   1   0
> ```

You can then very easily `cbind()` to the original data frame, i.e.

```
x2 <- x %>% 
  gather(var, val, -id) %>% 
  spread(val, var, fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-id), funs(replace(., . != 0, 1)))

cbind(x, x2)
#   id proc1 proc2 proc3 proc4 id PROC1 PROC2 PROC3 UX1 UX2 UX3
#1  1   UX1   UX2 PROC1 PROC3  1     1     0     1   1   1   0
#2  2   UX3   UX1 PROC2 PROC3  2     0     1     1   1   0   1
#3  3   UX2   UX1 PROC3 PROC1  3     1     0     1   1   1   0
```

**NOTE:** As @mmn points out, we can `merge` instead of `cbind`, i.e.

```
x %>%
  gather(var, val, - id) %>%
  spread(val, var, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-id), funs(replace(., . != 0, 1))) %>%
  left_join(x, ., by = 'id')

#  id col1 col2  col3  col4 PROC1 PROC2 PROC3 UX1 UX2 UX3
#1  1  UX1  UX2 PROC1 PROC3     1     0     1   1   1   0
#2  2  UX3  UX1 PROC2 PROC3     0     1     1   1   0   1
#3  3  UX2  UX1 PROC3 PROC1     1     0     1   1   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a change in the column names after I submited the first time and called them "col1" "col2". I think I will change them back, because you have used the first format of the data.

Comment: Names don't matter. You 'd still get the same result

Comment: @ Sotos. Yes you are rigth waste of time changing the names back. PS I am glad you used the tidyverse...

Comment: @Sotos Just a small proposal: Instead of cbind, we could do a left_join(x,x2, by="id).? Gets rid of double id column and is safer imo.

Comment: @ Sotos & mmn: I have another question: Now that I have the numeric dummy columns I want to make a distance matrix with the dist function. Assume my ID column is now character. When I calculate `dist(x2)` and `dist(x2[2:7])` i.e. I when exclude the id column I get two different results?? How can the dist function work when there is a character column?? Generally what should I do with my "ID" column when calculating a distance matrix? Should I put them as row.names? I usually use the tidyverse and tibbles...

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, suggesting also a data.table alternative:

```
# load the data table package
library(data.table)

# create the sample data set
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
                col1=c("UX1", "UX3", "UX2"),
                col2=c("UX2", "UX1", "UX1"),
                col3=c("PROC1", "PROC2", "PROC3"),
                col4=c("PROC3", "PROC3", "PROC1")
)

# convert data frame to data table
x <- data.table(x)

# first convert data to long format using melt function
# then use cast to go back to wide format, convert "value" variable to columns and check where are missing values
# then join on the original data set
x[dcast(melt(x, "id"), id ~ value, fun = function(x) sum(!is.na(x))), on = "id"]
```